# Downloaded file's names are not updating after download

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, firefox

I have a user that when he is downloading a csv file from a specific website, the file does not get it's name changed properly after download.
In chrome the file name looks like `XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX.csv` and in firefox the filename looks like `XXXXXXXX.csv` where the Xs are characters/digits.

The filename should be `PurchaseHistory_{todays date}.csv`.

When I and other users downloads files from the same website, the name is changed properly after download.  I tried hard refreshing the site. His chrome installation has extension but firefox is a clean download. We tried edge and it does the same thing chrome does(I'm assuming because it is built on chromium).

Comment: Welcome to [su]. Has Windows all the critical updates installed? Is Chrome updated to the last version? Have you already tried in incongnito modo?

Comment: I forgot to try incognito mode! That seemed to work but I'm confused as to the steps forward since it doesn't work on a fresh install of firefox neither.  I tried clearing the cache for the website, but not the cookies yet.  I will have the user try disabling their extensions on Monday when they are back in the office as well to see if we can find the culprit.  Thanks!

Comment: I actually got permission to work on it today. I cleared the specific cookies for the site and it is back to working.  It looks like firefox imported the cookies when the user installed it.

Comment: Great. Thanks for sharing. Whenever you have time, please take a look to [Looking for a canonical about troubleshooting issues about using web applications?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/14891/152004). It's a quite long post that incluide a section about things to try to start troubleshooting problems like this. Maybe you can't leave a comment there yet, but if you find it interesting or have a suggestion, please leave a comment here.

Comment: I added a link to the linked meta question... that should allow you to leave a comment on it (no pressure, just mentioning this b/c you appear with the "new contributor" tag)

Comment: Honestly, I think the issue is making sure the canonical pops up correctly in the see similar section while they are asking the question.  I can think of a few github repos that before posting a bug they require system information and performing basic troubleshooting steps.  This information is then used to fill in a template that is placed in the beginning section of the report.  I really like this style but I feel it would feel shoehorned if used on stack sites because of enforceability issues and the wide breadth of topics that would be covered.

Comment: I would see it needing several templates and this would cause confusion amongst questioners about which template to use. To contrast this, the idea of quick links to post under the comment of a question to run through basic troubleshooting steps if the user hasn't listed their methodology may be useful. I apologize if I am misunderstanding your post.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback. Due to the open and broad scope of this site I don't think that in the short term it will be possible to make that the similar section work properly for any user.... eventually, once the users learn this community workings, the similar section will work better from them. I think that the always will be some sort of back and fort, i.e., a stablished user might add a link to a canonical question with tips or will add the appropriate tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting page cookies was the answer. Important things to note:

1. Don't trust user when they claim it is a fresh install.(Firefox can import cookies for seamless browser transition)
2. Hard refreshes on chrome DO NOT reset cookies, just cache, so issues may persist after hard refresh.

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation (See also: [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/).